# Clearing app data without waiting for it to be counted

Tags: applications, 4.2-jelly-bean

When I need to clear an app's data, the "Clear Data" button is greyed out until Android has finished counting how much of it there is. Sometimes it never completes, and I need to force quit Settings and try again.

This is, obviously, a complete pain.

Given that I don't care how much data the app has stored — I just want it to be zero bytes — is there a way to force Android to enable the button and let me clear the app data without waiting for it to be counted first?

(I have a Nexus 7, which updated to 4.2 pretty sharply after I got it, so I don't know if this is a 4.2 bug or a poor design decision which has been around for ages…)

Comment: That issue bugs me in Android 5.1.1 as well.